# nginx error adding proxy cache to multiple servers or locations

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

http global config

```
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/temp/cache_one levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_one:100m inactive=7d max_size=30g;
    proxy_cache_key $scheme://$host$request_uri;
```

server config

```
server {
    listen 7777;
    include /tmp/nginx/conf/open_cache.conf;
        location /sample {
        include /tmp/nginx/conf/do_cache.conf;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.184:10071/sample;
    }   
    location /BDS {
        include /tmp/nginx/conf/do_cache.conf;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.184:18741/BDS;
    }   
}

server {
    listen 7788;
    include /tmp/nginx/conf/open_cache.conf;
    location / {
        include /tmp/nginx/conf/do_cache.conf;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.184:11202;
    }
}
```

open cache config

```
set $nocache 1;
if ( $request_uri  ~ "^/(.*\.)(gif|jpg|png|css|js|flv|ico|swf|woff|svg|ico)$" ) {  
    set $nocache 0;
}
```

do cache config

```
proxy_no_cache $nocache;
proxy_cache_bypass $nocache;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header SET-COOKIE;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
proxy_cache_valid 200 301 206 7d;
expires 30d;
```

This is a test environment with multiple servers and locations. When I turn on only one location, the cache is fine, but when I turn on all of them, the access cookies are lost in some environments.Is there a way to enable proxy cache for all environments in a large number of servers and locations?

Comment: Can you show me full error logs?

Comment: @anamul
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested again and found that the above is missing proxy_cache cache_one, after adding the static resource cache of both location environments are normal, but still can not log in, I think it is because proxy_hide_header makes the dynamic request lost session, but if I do not use proxy_hide_header will cause the static request contains set-cookie, please ask if there is a way to solve it

Comment: @anamul
Can I delete only the set-cookie from a static request?